# Uncaught exception 'CacheException' with message 'Cache engine _cake_core_ is not properly configured

Tags: php, cakephp, centos, cakephp-2.0, server

I create a application with CAKEPHP it works fine. When I transfer from one server to another server it create some problem.
I have changed file permission ap/tmp folder with 777 still give error

Error

[image]

And my Server folder permission

[image]

Answer (score 12):

You need to create these 2 folders inside **cache** folder

`app/tmp/cache/models` and
`app/tmp/cache/persistent`

Make them writeable too.